# Create An Ordered List From Similar Lists

Tags: python, list

I have many lists of bus stops. 
Each list represents stops taken by a bus on a single journey.
The journey path is the same but the bus may stop at any stop.

I want to create a complete list of all stops in ORDER.

Below are three sample bus journeys.

```
bus_1 = ["5171","1337","1341","1350","1352","1357","320","278","10","15","215","218","1623","1624","7347"]

bus_2 = ["5171","2976","2979","2981","2991","2992","1326","1327","1329","1331","1336","1337","1339","1340","1342","1345","1350","1354","1357","1359","320","278","12","15","17","21","205","215","216","218","1624","1626","1627","7347"]

bus_3 = ["5171","2977" "2978","2991","1325","1326","1327","1329","1330","1331","1332","1333","1337","1340","1341","1342","1344","1345","1347","1348","1352","1353","1354","1355","1357","1359","320","278","10","12","14","15","17","19","21","85","204","215","218","219","220","1622","1623","1624","1625","1626","1627","7347"]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the expect result.

Comment: What about duplicates?

Comment: what ORDER exactly?

Comment: So 5171 is the first stop on the route. 7347 is the last stop. The bus travels the length of the route each time only stopping at random stops but always in the same order and the bus route is fixed. I need to create a master list of all stops in order.

Comment: The first stop is easy! Post the desired output in full as bruno suggests

Comment: Your lists contain strings, not integers. I hope you're aware of that. So it is "5171", not 5171. If you just naive sort the list, "1337" will be before "15".

Comment: You may need a sort index to map the order of the stops

Comment: I'll try and post a desired output although it may take some time.

Comment: This is not universally possible. If you have the lists [1, 5, 10], [1,3,10] and [1, 7, 10] an algorithm cannot determine if the "correct" order is [1,3,5,7,10] or [1,5,3,7,10] - both are valid from the sub-routes.

Comment: The value of the strings is not important. Whats important is their order. For instance "5171" is always the first stop so it should be first in the list. "2977" always comes before "1337" and so on. I have a many hundreds of such lists. With enough input can I get a reliable master list?

Comment: @ChristianKönig Spot on! For example in `bus_2` there is a sequence: `"2991","2992","1326"` and in `bus_3` there is a sequence: `"2991","1325","1326"`. So how do we tell if "2992" is before "1325" or not?

Comment: @GavinHinfey: my example uses numbers, because it is easier to type 1 than "1". The algorithmic problem stays the same. It is not generally possible to determine the order, if there is not enough overlap between sub-routes.

Comment: @ChristianKönig then maybe OP is going to accept any of these orderings as "correct"?

Comment: @Błotosmętek You are right, I should have added "without ambiguities".

Comment: @cezer that is correct. However I may have another list that delineates that. For example another bus could of stopped at both "2992" and "1325"

Comment: @GavinHinfey Is you problem description resembling a graph or something like that? Because I feel like there is simply information missing in the lists.

Comment: what about distance between stops, that would be handy

Comment: @bbastu the point is that no 1 list represents the complete route with all stops. I am trying to create that from routes with only partial stops.

Comment: @GavinHinfey I think we get that. But how do you know which stop comes first. You must have positional information. A weighted graph maybe that tells you the distance of stops from each other. Then you could try to minimize the overall path weight which would be way more work than simply sorting lists. This way, as stated by Christian König it is simply not universally possible.

Comment: As Christian König stated above we may get an answer that is not universally correct when we compare the lists. However when we compare enough lists this would refine the result?  I have GPS data and certainly will go that route if a solution using these lists cannot be found.

Comment: I believe this is indeed a graph theory problem. What your sub-routes define is a partial order relation (which may be or not be a total order relation). I'll make a try at it.

Comment: Do you have any further information? For example, the expected arrival times of the bus at each stop? From that it might be a little more plausible to calculate the "order"

Comment: @asongtoruin yes I have that but I don't believe its relevant. Some buses reach the destination in 10 minutes vs 40 mins given weather, traffic and a myriad of factors.

Comment: it could help if there was weather the whole route would be affected and you could calculate some average across all the days

Comment: @GavinHinfey yes but in the cases as discussed previously where it is unclear what order the stops should go in (i.e. between 5171 and 2991) the journey time information could be used as a proxy for order.

Comment: @asongtoruin that is perhaps correct. However I believe I have enough input data (I have more than given above) to remove those ambiguities by just using lists.

Comment: Imagine 4 bus stops form a perfect square, or 3 form an equilateral triangle, it would be impossible/arbitrary to determine the order in these cases

Comment: can you provide more routes? I've gotten up to `[5171, 2976, 2979, 2981, 2991, 2992, 1326, 1327, 1329, 1330, 1331, 1336, 1337, 1339, 1340, 1341, 1350, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1357, 1359, 320, 278, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 205, 215, 216, 218, 219, 220, 1622, 1623, 1624, 1625, 1626, 1627, 7347]` but it is still missing some stops

Comment: The lists you have provided are ambiguous. You should provide more information.

Comment: also you're missing a comma `"2977" "2978"` in `bus_3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is my solution - please check if it satisfies your needs. I have replaced separate variables for sub-routes with a dictionary, hope it is not a problem.

```
routes = {
    'bus_1': ["5171","1337","1341","1350","1352","1357","320","278","10","15","215","218","1623","1624","7347"],
    'bus_2': ["5171","2976","2979","2981","2991","2992","1326","1327","1329","1331","1336","1337","1339","1340","1342","1345","1350","1354","1357","1359","320","278","12","15","17","21","205","215","216","218","1624","1626","1627","7347"],
    'bus_3': ["5171","2977", "2978","2991","1325","1326","1327","1329","1330","1331","1332","1333","1337","1340","1341","1342","1344","1345","1347","1348","1352","1353","1354","1355","1357","1359","320","278","10","12","14","15","17","19","21","85","204","215","218","219","220","1622","1623","1624","1625","1626","1627","7347"]
}

stops = set()
stop_pairs = set()
for route in routes.values():
    stops.update(route)
    for i in range(1,len(route)):
        # each pair is correctly ordered
        stop_pairs.add(tuple(route[i-1:i+1]))
# at this point, 'stops' is the set of all stops
# and 'stop_pairs' is a set of tuples representing sequence of stops
ordered_stops = []
while stops:
    # let's look for the minimal elements in stops
    minimals = set()
    for stop in stops:
        if not any((s, stop) in stop_pairs for s in stops):
            # there is no such s that s precedes stop 
            minimals.add(stop)
    ordered_stops.append(minimals)
    stops.difference_update(minimals)
print(ordered_stops)
```

My result is:

> [{'5171'}, {'2977', '2976'}, {'2979', '2978'}, {'2981'}, {'2991'}, {'1325', '2992'}, {'1326'}, {'1327'}, {'1329'}, {'1330'}, {'1331'}, {'1336', '1332'}, {'1333'}, {'1337'}, {'1339'}, {'1340'}, {'1341'}, {'1342'}, {'1344'}, {'1345'}, {'1347', '1350'}, {'1348'}, {'1352'}, {'1353'}, {'1354'}, {'1355'}, {'1357'}, {'1359'}, {'320'}, {'278'}, {'10'}, {'12'}, {'14'}, {'15'}, {'17'}, {'19'}, {'21'}, {'205', '85'}, {'204'}, {'215'}, {'216'}, {'218'}, {'219'}, {'220'}, {'1622'}, {'1623'}, {'1624'}, {'1625'}, {'1626'}, {'1627'}, {'7347'}]

**UPDATE**: I have just noticed that my program can be easily generalized to produce variant solutions, and edited it accordingly. Now, the resulting list consists of sets of stops that are of equal precedence (ie. stops within each set can be reshuffled). Apparently, there are six such sets:  {'2977', '2976'}, {'2979', '2978'}, {'1325', '2992'},  {'1336', '1332'}, {'1347', '1350'}, {'205', '85'}.

Comment: As with depperm's answer this looks as correct as can reasonably be achieved with the data provided. I will go and source more data to test further. I have an answer which I will post below. It is not as concise as this however.

Comment: This works. I put 68 buses into it and was left with 3 sets of equal precedence. With enough buses these should be eliminated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get close but I think you need more routes to get a complete route. Some of the values it couldn't add didn't have enough similar surrounding elements, but this may get you along the right path.

```
bus_1 = ["5171","1337","1341","1350","1352","1357","320","278","10","15","215","218","1623","1624","7347"]   
bus_2 = ["5171","2976","2979","2981","2991","2992","1326","1327","1329","1331","1336","1337","1339","1340","1342","1345","1350","1354","1357","1359","320","278","12","15","17","21","205","215","216","218","1624","1626","1627","7347"]
bus_3 = ["5171","2977", "2978","2991","1325","1326","1327","1329","1330","1331","1332","1333","1337","1340","1341","1342","1344","1345","1347","1348","1352","1353","1354","1355","1357","1359","320","278","10","12","14","15","17","19","21","85","204","215","218","219","220","1622","1623","1624","1625","1626","1627","7347"]

buses=[bus_1,bus_2,bus_3]

added=set()
final=bus_1[:]
temp=bus_1+bus_2+bus_3
i=0
x=0
while set(final) != set(temp):
  # get 2 elements which we'll see if they're in final route
  if x<len(buses):
    t=buses[x][i:i+2]
  else:
    t=final[i:i+2]
  try:
    a=final.index(t[0])
    b=final.index(t[1])
  except:
    a=b=-1
  # check if in final and not next to each other, and not added yet
  for q,bus in enumerate(buses):
    if x!=q and t[0] in bus and t[1] in bus and a+1==b and (t[0],t[1]) not in added:
      u=bus.index(t[0])
      v=bus.index(t[1])
      final[a:b]=bus[u:v]

      added.add((t[0],t[1]))
      i=0
      x=0

  if x<len(buses):
    for q,bus in enumerate(buses):
      if q==x and i+2<len(bus):
        i+=1
      elif q==x and i+2==len(bus):
        x+=1
        i=0
  elif x==len(buses)+1 and i+2<len(final):
    i+=1
  else:
    x+=1
    i=0

  if x>len(buses)+1:
    break

print("final route(incomplete)")
print(final)
print('unique stops')
print(set(temp))
#this is my result
#mine=['5171', '2976', '2979', '2981', '2991', '2992', '1326', '1327', '1329', '1330', '1331', '1336', '1337', '1339', '1340', '1341', '1350', '1352', '1353', '1354', '1355', '1357', '1359', '320', '278', '10', '12', '14', '15', '17', '19', '21', '205', '215', '216', '218', '219', '220', '1622', '1623', '1624', '1625', '1626', '1627', '7347']
#this is what you probably want
#goal=['5171', '2976', '2977', '2978', '2979', '2981', '2991', '2992', '1325', '1326', '1327', '1329', '1330', '1331', '1332', '1333', '1336', '1337', '1339', '1340', '1341', '1342', '1344', '1345', '1347', '1348', '1350', '1352', '1353', '1354', '1355', '1357', '1359', '320', '278', '10', '12', '14', '15', '17', '19', '21', '85','204', 205', '215', '216', '218', '219', '220', '1622', '1623', '1624', '1625', '1626', '1627', '7347']

#unable to add
#['204', '85', '1348', '1347', '1342', '1344', '1345', '1333', '1332', '1325', '2978']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# All three buses in 1 2d list.
route = ["5171","1337","1341","1350","1352","1357","320","278","10","15","215","218","1623","1624","7347"],["5171","2976","2979","2981","2991","2992","1326","1327","1329","1331","1336","1337","1339","1340","1342","1345","1350","1354","1357","1359","320","278","12","15","17","21","205","215","216","218","1624","1626","1627","7347"],["5171","2977","2978","2991","1325","1326","1327","1329","1330","1331","1332","1333","1337","1340","1341","1342","1344","1345","1347","1348","1352","1353","1354","1355","1357","1359","320","278","10","12","14","15","17","19","21","85","204","215","218","219","220","1622","1623","1624","1625","1626","1627","7347"]

temp = set()
out = {}

# remove dupes by adding each stop to a set.
for journey in route:
    for stop in journey:
        temp.add(stop)

# create a dictionary where the key is a unique stop
# the value is a list of two empty sets.
for i in temp:
    out[i] = [set(),set()]

for i in temp:
    for journey in route:
        if i in journey:

            # add stops which occur before this stop to one dictionary
            for before in journey[0:journey.index(i)]:
                out[i][0].add(before)

            # and stops which occur after this stop to the other dictionary
            for after in journey[journey.index(i):-1]:
                out[i][1].add(after)

# create a template final list of unique stops from the set.
final_list = list(temp)

# iterate ove the dictionary
for key, value in out.items():

    # get list of what stops should be ordered before the current stop
    before_set = value[0]
    # and a list of those that should be after.
    after_set = value[1]


    for b in before_set:

        # if the current value is not where is should be move it.
        if final_list.index(b) > final_list.index(key):

            temp = final_list.index(key)
            final_list.insert(final_list.index(b), key)
            final_list.pop(temp)

    for a in after_set:

        # if the current value is not where is should be move it.
        if final_list.index(a) < final_list.index(key):

            temp = final_list.index(key)
            final_list.insert(final_list.index(a), key)
            final_list.pop(temp+1)

# and run again in the opposite direction.
final_list = final_list[::-1]

for key, value in out.items():

    before_set = value[0]
    after_set = value[1]

    for b in before_set:

        if final_list.index(b) > final_list.index(key):

            temp = final_list.index(key)
            final_list.insert(final_list.index(b), key)
            final_list.pop(temp)

    for a in after_set:

        if final_list.index(a) < final_list.index(key):

            temp = final_list.index(key)
            final_list.insert(final_list.index(a), key)
            final_list.pop(temp+1)

print(final_list)
```